# Convert an XML file to PDF using XSLT and XSL-FO/FOP

Tags: java, xml, xsl-fo

I'm trying to convert an XML file to a PDF file using XSL-FO, I found the code in this example:

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/xmlgraphics/fop/trunk/examples/embedding/java/embedding/ExampleXML2PDF.java?view=markup

but I receive this Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xmlgraphics/image/loader/impl/ImageRawPNG
at org.apache.fop.render.pdf.PDFImageHandlerRawPNG.getSupportedImageClass(PDFImageHandlerRawPNG.java:51)
at org.apache.fop.render.ImageHandlerRegistry.addHandler(ImageHandlerRegistry.java:97)
at org.apache.fop.render.ImageHandlerRegistry.discoverHandlers(ImageHandlerRegistry.java:169)
at org.apache.fop.render.ImageHandlerRegistry.<init>(ImageHandlerRegistry.java:64)
at org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory.<init>(FopFactory.java:168)
at org.apache.fop.apps.FopFactory.newInstance(FopFactory.java:177)
at searchManagement.export.PdfExporter.main(PdfExporter.java:77)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xmlgraphics.image.loader.impl.ImageRawPNG
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 7 more
```

Do you have some advices?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This error means that one of the classes you are using is trying to use the class org/apache/xmlgraphics/image/loader/impl/ImageRawPNG but can't find it.

What you need to do, is find the jar that contains that class and add it to the classpath.